# How to query using multiple joins in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 3 Models - `Datapoints`, `Dimensions` and a model that binds these 2 Models together - `DatapointDimensions`

```
class Datapoint < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :metric
  has_many :datapoint_dimensions
  has_many :dimensions, :through => :datapoint_dimensions

  validates :metric, :presence => true
  validates :value, :presence => true
  validates :timestamp, :presence => true
  validates :duration, :presence => true
end

class Dimension < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dimension_group
  belongs_to :parent_dimension, class_name: "Dimension", foreign_key: "parent_dimension_id"
  has_many :child_dimensions, class_name: "Dimension", foreign_key: "parent_dimension_id"
  has_many :datapoint_dimensions
  has_many :datapoints, through: :datapoint_dimensions

  validates :dimension_group, :presence => true
  validates :code, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
end

class DatapointDimension < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :datapoint
  belongs_to :dimension

  validates :datapoint, :presence => true
  validates :dimension, :presence => true
end
```

Now, I need to write a query where i check for a Datapoint which has a specific metric, a specific duration and in DatapointDimension, has a combination of 3 dimensions

Table data is something like this

```
----datapoints----
id      metric_id       duration
1          13            1M2012
2          13            1M2012

----datapoint_dimensions----
datapoint_id              dimension_id
   1                           2
   1                           45
   1                          127
   2                           2
   2                           38
```

I want to be able to search for Datapoints with metric_id = 13 AND which are associated with dimensions 2, 45 and 127 (All 3 of them) in datapoint_dimensions

I tried

```
Datapoint.where(metric_id: 13).where(duration: '1M2012').joins(:datapoint_dimensions).where(datapoint_dimensions: {dimension_id: 2, dimension_id: 45, dimension_id: 127}).readonly(false)
```

This returns both the datapoints (id = 1 and id = 2)
But I want it to return only the datapoint with id = 1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for your reply. I tried this query with only 2 dimensions (2 & 45) and it still returned me the dimension 1. I want the query to return datapoint 1 only if dimensions 2, 45 & 127 - all three are there

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I believe I know the reason why you're seeing this. Before I write anything concrete, what version of rails are you using?

Comment: Hey Paul.. it is Rails 3.1.3

Comment: Convert your code to sql (apply `to_sql`) and post it

Comment: Interesting...  The SQL query only shows one of the 3 dimensions...     SELECT `datapoints`.* FROM `datapoints` 
 INNER JOIN `datapoint_dimensions` ON `datapoint_dimensions`.`datapoint_id` = `datapoints`.`id` 
 WHERE `datapoints`.`metric_id` = 13 AND `datapoints`.`duration` = '1M2014' AND `datapoint_dimensions`.`dimension_id` = 2

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're seeing is related to the `where` clause containing the `dimension_id` parameters. In your case, you're passing a hash with three key-value pairs, however the names of the keys are in fact the same. As a result, when you think you're passing

```
{dimension_id: 2, dimension_id: 45, dimension_id: 127}
```

You're actually passing

```
{dimension_id: 2}
```

Because you're essentially overriding (or squashing) the other keys of the same name. *Note: The "squashing" behaviour might be different in other versions of Ruby. On mine (Ruby 2.0+), my parameter is 127, whereas you indicated 2.*

Since you said you want to pull up the `Datapoint` object that contains all three of those `dimension_id` values, one way you can accomplish this is by using a `WHERE ... IN` and a subquery to filter results that don't match exactly. Its a bit more complicated than your original version, but try this (formatted for readability):

```
Datapoint.joins(:datapoint_dimensions)
         .where(metric_id: 13, duration: '1M2012')
         .where(datapoint_dimensions: {dimension_id: [2, 45, 127]})
         .where("datapoint_id != (#{                 

            DatapointDimension
              .select(:datapoint_id)
              .where("dimension_id NOT IN (?)", [2, 45, 127]).to_sql

         })").group(:datapoint_id)
```

Note the subquery, and the awkward string interpolation. There might be a better way to write this, however this is the only way I think think of at the moment.

Rails 4 has the `where.not` function, which makes this subquery a little less awkward, however essentially this query will return every row where the `dimension_id` is 2, 45, and 127.

Also note that the `.where` clauses can be squished in to one method call if you prefer, I'm simply separating it out for readability.

Let me know if that makes a difference.

**EDIT**

If the above does not work, try this instead:

```
Datapoint.joins(:datapoint_dimensions)
         .where(metric_id: 13, duration: '1M2012')
         .where(datapoint_dimensions: {dimension_id: [2, 45, 127]})
         .where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM datapoint_dimensions dd2 WHERE dd2.datapoint_id = datapoint_dimensions.datapoint_id AND dimension_id NOT IN (2, 45, 127))")
         .group(:datapoint_id)
```

Comment: Hey Paul, unfortunately, this query doesn't return any Datapoints. My requirement is to check a datapoint which satisfies all of these - 1.  a specific Duration, 2. a specific metric id 3. a specific set of dimensions in datapoint_dimensions for that datapoint

Comment: @user3585908 Hmm, works fine for me, given the data and structure you showed above. Try the edit I just made (with the plain SQL dependent subquery). Perhaps there's something different with the way the subquery works in the previous version.